# Implement move-esque behavior on &mut self function to allow calls thru ?Sized owner?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to have my cake and eat it too with trait vs. enum representations of an IR.

I had the idea that a lot of what I want could be achieved by having `enum` versions of traits, the branches of which contain only the data at that node of the AST, then boxes containing the relevant trait. The `trait` and `enum` versions convert back and forth into each other, giving me the dynamic matching of `enum`s along with the flexibility and power of traits. The downside is some boilerplate around including the `enum` versions and passing back and forth, but that seems like it might be worth the cost.

This is *almost* working, except for one thing: for other reasons, (I think?) I need to implement these traits on `Box<T : Trait + ?Sized>`. That `?Sized` is a problem, because it prevents me (I think?) from calling a `self method on the boxed object.

I had the further idea that I could get around that by having a private helper function on the trait, which would take an `&mut self` rather than `self`, and thus the `Box` impls could call it. The actual struct-backed `impl`s could then use the `&mut` version by moving their contents (which should just be some metadata and a few box pointers) to the return. Essentially these `&mut` functions would destroy whatever they were called on, but (I think?) the visibility can be restricted in a way where they'll never be called except as the implementation of a function on owned data.

You can see the general idea of that at the top of the code below, plus a bunch more implementation.

```
trait IR : 'static + std::fmt::Debug{
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data>;
    fn to_ir_enum(self) -> IREnum;
    fn to_ir_enum_mut(&mut self) -> IREnum;
}
impl<T : IR + ?Sized> IR for Box<T>{
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data>{
        self.as_ref().evaluate()
    }
    fn to_ir_enum(mut self) -> IREnum{
        //(*self).to_ir_enum() //If I could do this it would be easy, but T is not sized!
        self.to_ir_enum_mut()
    }
    fn to_ir_enum_mut(&mut self) -> IREnum{
        self.as_mut().to_ir_enum_mut()
    }
}
trait Data : IR{
    fn to_data_enum(self) -> DataEnum;
    fn to_data_enum_mut(&mut self) -> DataEnum;
}
impl<T : Data + ?Sized> Data for Box<T>{
    fn to_data_enum(mut self) -> DataEnum{
        self.to_data_enum_mut()
    }
    fn to_data_enum_mut(&mut self) -> DataEnum{
        self.as_mut().to_data_enum_mut()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct BoolLiteral(bool);
impl IR for BoolLiteral{
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data>{
        Box::new(BoolLiteral(self.0))
    }
    fn to_ir_enum(self) -> IREnum{
        IREnum::BoolLiteral(self.0)
    }
    fn to_ir_enum_mut(&mut self) -> IREnum{
        IREnum::BoolLiteral(self.0)
    }
}
impl Data for BoolLiteral{
    fn to_data_enum(self) -> DataEnum{
        DataEnum::BoolLiteral(self.0)
    }
    fn to_data_enum_mut(&mut self) -> DataEnum{
        DataEnum::BoolLiteral(self.0)
    }
}


#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tuple<T>(Vec<T>);
impl<T : IR> IR for Tuple<T>{
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data>{
        let data_vec = self.0.iter().map(|x| x.evaluate()).collect();
        let data_tuple = Tuple(data_vec);
        Box::new(data_tuple)
    }
    fn to_ir_enum(self) -> IREnum{
        IREnum::Tuple(self.0.into_iter().map(|x| {let boxed : Box<dyn IR> = Box::new(x); boxed} ).collect())
    }
    fn to_ir_enum_mut(&mut self) -> IREnum{
        //let mut new_vec: Vec<Box<dyn IR>> = Vec::new();
        let new_vec : Vec<T> = self.0.drain(..).collect();
        IREnum::Tuple(new_vec.into_iter().map(|x| {let boxed : Box<dyn IR> = Box::new(x); boxed} ).collect())
    }
}
impl<T : Data> Data for Tuple<T>{
    fn to_data_enum(self) -> DataEnum{
        DataEnum::Tuple(self.0.into_iter().map(|x| {let boxed : Box<dyn Data> = Box::new(x); boxed} ).collect())
    }
    fn to_data_enum_mut(&mut self) -> DataEnum{
    let new_vec: Vec<T> = self.0.drain(..).collect();
       DataEnum::Tuple(new_vec.into_iter().map(|x| {let boxed : Box<dyn Data> = Box::new(x); boxed} ).collect())
    }
}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct IfThenElse<T1, T2, T3>{
    condition : T1,
    then_branch : T2,
    else_branch : T3
}
impl<T1 : IR, T2 : IR, T3 : IR> IR for IfThenElse<T1, T2, T3>{
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data>{
        let condition: Box<dyn Data> = self.condition.evaluate();
        let condition_enum = condition.to_data_enum();
        match condition_enum{
            DataEnum::BoolLiteral(true) => self.then_branch.evaluate(),
            DataEnum::BoolLiteral(false) => self.else_branch.evaluate(),
            _ => panic!("IfThenElse condition not a BoolLiteral")
        }
    }
    fn to_ir_enum(self) -> IREnum{
        IREnum::IfThenElse{
            condition: Box::new(self.condition),
            then_branch: Box::new(self.then_branch),
            else_branch: Box::new(self.else_branch)
        }
    }
    fn to_ir_enum_mut(&mut self) -> IREnum{
         todo!();
    }
}

enum DataEnum{
    BoolLiteral(bool),
    Tuple(Vec<Box<dyn Data>>),
}
impl DataEnum{
    pub fn to_trait(self) -> Box<dyn Data>{
        match self{
            DataEnum::BoolLiteral(b) => Box::new(BoolLiteral(b)),
            DataEnum::Tuple(v) => Box::new(Tuple(v))
        }
    }
}

enum IREnum{
    BoolLiteral(bool),
    Tuple(Vec<Box<dyn IR>>),
    IfThenElse{
        condition: Box<dyn IR>,
        then_branch: Box<dyn IR>,
        else_branch: Box<dyn IR>
    },
}
impl IREnum{
    pub fn to_trait(self) -> Box<dyn IR>{
        match self{
            IREnum::BoolLiteral(b) => Box::new(BoolLiteral(b)),
            IREnum::Tuple(v) => Box::new(Tuple(v)),
            IREnum::IfThenElse{condition, then_branch, else_branch} => Box::new(IfThenElse{
                condition: condition,
                then_branch: then_branch,
                else_branch: else_branch
            })
        }
    }
}

pub fn run() {
    let lit_true = BoolLiteral(true);
    let lit_false = BoolLiteral(false);
    let tuple_1 = Tuple(vec![Box::new(lit_true), Box::new(lit_false)]);
    let tuple_2 = Tuple(vec![Box::new(lit_false), Box::new(lit_true)]);
    let if_then_else = IfThenElse{
        condition: lit_true,
        then_branch: tuple_1,
        else_branch: tuple_2
    };
    let tuple_3 = Tuple(vec![Box::new(lit_true), Box::new(lit_false)]);
    let tuple_4: Box<dyn IR> = Box::new(Tuple(vec![Box::new(lit_true), Box::new(lit_false)]));
    let big_tuple = Tuple(vec![tuple_4, Box::new(lit_true)]);
    let if_then_else_outer = IfThenElse{
        condition: lit_false,
        then_branch: if_then_else,
        else_branch: big_tuple
    };
    let result = if_then_else_outer.evaluate();
    println!("Result: {:?}", result);
}
```

The above code actually compiles and works, which is why I'm pretty convinced that what I'm doing is possible. `Tuple` implements the behavior by emptying its vector into an owned one, and using that to create the return type; the literals can simply copy the primitive data they own.

However, you'll notice:

```
fn to_ir_enum_mut(&mut self) -> IREnum{
         todo!();
    }
```

I'm sure I could do something with making `IfThenElse` box its contents, or require all of these types to have some sort of default, or something, but I feel like I'm very far out on a branch here, and re-implementing things that already exist in some simpler form. So:

- Is there some easier way to let me implement the `to_enum(self)` methods when `Self : ?Sized`?
- If not, is there some way to generically implement the `to_enum_mut(&mut self)` functions, when I know that the referenced object can be effectively destroyed?
- If not, what's the best way to implement this over the various form of struct contents? (i.e., when they're in a `Box`, a `Vec`, or just an owned `T`?
- Or is this an occasion to actually put lifetimes on the `enum` stuff, and have the enum just hold references into the owned data?

**EDIT: Why not just enums?**

- I've found recursive enums to become painful if I have to attach type parameters to them, when it's possible for the type parameters on the children to be different from those on the parent
- I expect to have a handful of these traits/enums in scope, most of which will share most of their variants; I'd like to have a single implementation of shared functions for those variants
- While I want the specific variant to be "dynamic" in that I need to be able to pattern match against it, I'd still like to have static, type-level reasoning about the flavor of node that exists - things like "a tuple is data iff its children are data".
- Having structures simultaneously belonging to two different types is helpful (for instance, my data structs are also IR structs).

All of that being said, I acknowledge this might be a bad idea and I might be creating more problems than I'm solving. I still want to get it working this way, tho, both to make a fair comparison to the enum-only model and in case the technique turns out to be useful in another context.

Comment: If you're always going to destroy the calling object, I don't think a `to_ir_enum_mut(&mut self)` method is the way to go. It's trying to move out of an object, but with the restriction that you still have to leave behind a valid object. Can you elaborate on why `?Sized` is problematic?

Comment: @BallpointBen Do you see the commented out line in `impl<T : IR + ?Sized> IR for Box<T>`? That's basically why `?Sized` is a problem - even tho I own the box, I can't call an owned function on what's in it because I don't know the size. (There might be an easy way around this but IDK what it is).

Comment: Note that your design is _extremely_ inefficient (it may not be a concern for you, though). For example, each roundtrip tuple dyn->tuple enum boxes all of the elements, so you can end up with `Box<Box<Box<Box<...>>>>`, all dynamically dispatched.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I figured I was probably making those `Box` chains - I figure there's some way to make a `box` function that would return a `Box<dyn SomeTrait>`, implemented by just returning `self` if it's called on something that's already `Boxed`. Other than that, for efficiency my big goal is that the back-and-forth conversion not actually go down the depth of the tree, just re-arrange stuff at the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods on traits can take `self: Box<Self>`, and they can be dispatched on trait objects:

```rust
trait IR: 'static + std::fmt::Debug {
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data>;
    fn to_ir_enum(self: Box<Self>) -> IREnum;
}

impl<T: IR + ?Sized> IR for Box<T> {
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data> {
        T::evaluate(&**self)
    }
    fn to_ir_enum(self: Box<Self>) -> IREnum {
        T::to_ir_enum(*self)
    }
}

trait Data: IR {
    fn to_data_enum(self: Box<Self>) -> DataEnum;
}

impl<T: Data + ?Sized> Data for Box<T> {
    fn to_data_enum(self: Box<Self>) -> DataEnum {
        T::to_data_enum(*self)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct BoolLiteral(bool);
impl IR for BoolLiteral {
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data> {
        Box::new(BoolLiteral(self.0))
    }
    fn to_ir_enum(self: Box<Self>) -> IREnum {
        IREnum::BoolLiteral(self.0)
    }
}
impl Data for BoolLiteral {
    fn to_data_enum(self: Box<Self>) -> DataEnum {
        DataEnum::BoolLiteral(self.0)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tuple<T>(Vec<T>);
impl<T: IR> IR for Tuple<T> {
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data> {
        let data_vec = self.0.iter().map(|x| x.evaluate()).collect();
        let data_tuple = Tuple(data_vec);
        Box::new(data_tuple)
    }
    fn to_ir_enum(self: Box<Self>) -> IREnum {
        IREnum::Tuple(
            self.0
                .into_iter()
                .map(|x| {
                    let boxed: Box<dyn IR> = Box::new(x);
                    boxed
                })
                .collect(),
        )
    }
}
impl<T: Data> Data for Tuple<T> {
    fn to_data_enum(self: Box<Self>) -> DataEnum {
        DataEnum::Tuple(
            self.0
                .into_iter()
                .map(|x| {
                    let boxed: Box<dyn Data> = Box::new(x);
                    boxed
                })
                .collect(),
        )
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct IfThenElse<T1, T2, T3> {
    condition: T1,
    then_branch: T2,
    else_branch: T3,
}
impl<T1: IR, T2: IR, T3: IR> IR for IfThenElse<T1, T2, T3> {
    fn evaluate(&self) -> Box<dyn Data> {
        let condition: Box<dyn Data> = self.condition.evaluate();
        let condition_enum = condition.to_data_enum();
        match condition_enum {
            DataEnum::BoolLiteral(true) => self.then_branch.evaluate(),
            DataEnum::BoolLiteral(false) => self.else_branch.evaluate(),
            _ => panic!("IfThenElse condition not a BoolLiteral"),
        }
    }
    fn to_ir_enum(self: Box<Self>) -> IREnum {
        IREnum::IfThenElse {
            condition: Box::new(self.condition),
            then_branch: Box::new(self.then_branch),
            else_branch: Box::new(self.else_branch),
        }
    }
}

enum DataEnum {
    BoolLiteral(bool),
    Tuple(Vec<Box<dyn Data>>),
}
impl DataEnum {
    pub fn to_trait(self) -> Box<dyn Data> {
        match self {
            DataEnum::BoolLiteral(b) => Box::new(BoolLiteral(b)),
            DataEnum::Tuple(v) => Box::new(Tuple(v)),
        }
    }
}

enum IREnum {
    BoolLiteral(bool),
    Tuple(Vec<Box<dyn IR>>),
    IfThenElse {
        condition: Box<dyn IR>,
        then_branch: Box<dyn IR>,
        else_branch: Box<dyn IR>,
    },
}
impl IREnum {
    pub fn to_trait(self) -> Box<dyn IR> {
        match self {
            IREnum::BoolLiteral(b) => Box::new(BoolLiteral(b)),
            IREnum::Tuple(v) => Box::new(Tuple(v)),
            IREnum::IfThenElse {
                condition,
                then_branch,
                else_branch,
            } => Box::new(IfThenElse {
                condition: condition,
                then_branch: then_branch,
                else_branch: else_branch,
            }),
        }
    }
}

pub fn run() {
    let lit_true = BoolLiteral(true);
    let lit_false = BoolLiteral(false);
    let tuple_1 = Tuple(vec![Box::new(lit_true), Box::new(lit_false)]);
    let tuple_2 = Tuple(vec![Box::new(lit_false), Box::new(lit_true)]);
    let if_then_else = IfThenElse {
        condition: lit_true,
        then_branch: tuple_1,
        else_branch: tuple_2,
    };
    let tuple_3 = Tuple(vec![Box::new(lit_true), Box::new(lit_false)]);
    let tuple_4: Box<dyn IR> = Box::new(Tuple(vec![Box::new(lit_true), Box::new(lit_false)]));
    let big_tuple = Tuple(vec![tuple_4, Box::new(lit_true)]);
    let if_then_else_outer = IfThenElse {
        condition: lit_false,
        then_branch: if_then_else,
        else_branch: big_tuple,
    };
    let result = if_then_else_outer.evaluate();
    println!("Result: {:?}", result);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=17b9c3928e8627b3c734972935cf4419).

There is a little inefficiency here due to the fact that we box even `Box`es, so we end with `Box<Box<...>>`. It shouldn't be a concern for you since you always box the values generically anyway, but there are ways to resolve it should you need that.

Comment: Is the way to resolve that to replace the `Box::new` calls with a method on the traits, which is backed by `Box::new` for the non-Box `impl`s and just returns `self` for the Box `impl`?

Comment: @EdwardPeters Doing so fully generically requires specialization, but you can do it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=79149cdd0802733c17e6e56ae30d191f.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the traits and then do everything through the enums, it gets pretty simple, although I don't know if this supports everything you need.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct BoolLiteral(bool);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tuple<T>(Vec<T>);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct IfThenElse<T1, T2, T3> {
    condition: T1,
    then_branch: T2,
    else_branch: T3,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum DataEnum {
    BoolLiteral(BoolLiteral),
    Tuple(Tuple<DataEnum>),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum IREnum {
    BoolLiteral(BoolLiteral),
    Tuple(Tuple<IREnum>),
    IfThenElse(Box<IfThenElse<IREnum, IREnum, IREnum>>),
}

impl IREnum {
    fn evaluate(&self) -> DataEnum {
        match self {
            IREnum::BoolLiteral(BoolLiteral(b)) => DataEnum::BoolLiteral(BoolLiteral(*b)),
            IREnum::Tuple(v) => {
                let data_vec = v.0.iter().map(|x| x.evaluate()).collect();
                let data_tuple = Tuple(data_vec);
                DataEnum::Tuple(data_tuple)
            }
            IREnum::IfThenElse(bx) => {
                let IfThenElse {
                    condition,
                    then_branch,
                    else_branch,
                } = &**bx;
                match condition.evaluate() {
                    DataEnum::BoolLiteral(BoolLiteral(true)) => then_branch.evaluate(),
                    DataEnum::BoolLiteral(BoolLiteral(false)) => else_branch.evaluate(),
                    _ => panic!("IfThenElse condition not a BoolLiteral"),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn run() {
    let lit_true = BoolLiteral(true);
    let lit_false = BoolLiteral(false);
    let tuple_1 = Tuple(vec![
        IREnum::BoolLiteral(lit_true),
        IREnum::BoolLiteral(lit_false),
    ]);
    let tuple_2 = Tuple(vec![
        IREnum::BoolLiteral(lit_false),
        IREnum::BoolLiteral(lit_true),
    ]);
    let if_then_else = IfThenElse {
        condition: IREnum::BoolLiteral(lit_true),
        then_branch: IREnum::Tuple(tuple_1),
        else_branch: IREnum::Tuple(tuple_2),
    };
    let result = IREnum::IfThenElse(Box::new(if_then_else)).evaluate();
    println!("Result: {:?}", result);
}

fn main() {
    run()
}
```

Comment: (Whoops, realize I had misread something in yours)

Comment: No, the tuples are the point - I realize I'm not showing off a lot of the reasons why in my example, but that's mostly due to it already being very long and trying to stay focused on the central question. Most of this comes down to being able to do more sophisticated type reasoning on the type level with traits, and implementing behaviors conditionally on the child types meeting various criteria.

Comment: I'll go ahead and acknowledge it might be a bad idea - the cost and overhead of this might not be worth it. But I still want to know if this can be done and how to do it - with a working implementation in front of me I'll be in a better place to compare it to the enum-only model, and I think there's a valid "How" question that exists independently of the "Why", if only for the possibility of the technique being useful in a different context.